# Testing with dual UI's

Tags: sahi

I have a browser based test program for testing a browser based application. This means that I need to record sequences that alternately manipulate the test program and then the application to check that it reacts correctly, so that I can perform automated testing.

How should I do this with SAHI?

I cannot see a way of recording two separate URL's concurrently. I have tried combining the two UI's using frames, and iframes, but I couldn't get SAHI to record in the frame/iframe.

I could modify the test program so that I can call it from scripts called by SAHI, but that rather defeats the object of having an automation tool...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1) Record the actions on the first web page using Sahi (script1)

2) Record the actions on the second web page (script2)

3) In script1, do this

```
// do steps for UI 1 as recorded in script1
_call(window.open("second url", "newWindow")); // open the second window
_selectWindow("newWindow"); // target the following steps on newWindow
// copy steps from script2 here
_selectWindow(); // return to base window
// perform further base window steps
// Use _selectWindow("newWindow") and _selectWindow() to switch between windows.
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,